# Django: how to render same webpage after submit form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, render

I have a index.html file which has the submit button. I want the functionality that when I click submit button, python function should get called in background but the rendering view of index.html should stay same. Right now every time I click on submit button a new copy of index.html is getting loaded. Here are my codes

index.html

```
<form action = "submit" method = "post">
     <p>latitude <input type = "text" id = "Latbox" name = "Latbox" /></p>
     <p>Longitdue <input type = "text" id = "Lonbox" name = "Lonbox" /b></p>
     <p><input type = "submit" value = "submit" /></p>
</form>
```

My views.py file is as follow :

```
from django.shortcuts import render 
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class HomePageView(TemplateView):
   def get(self, request, **kwargs):
     return render(request, 'index.html', context=None)


def submit(request):
  LAT=request.POST['Latbox']
  LON= request.POST['Lonbox']
  print (LAT, LON)
  return render(request,'index.html',context=None)
```

I am new to django. Can I get some pointer or answer as to how to solve this.

Comment: ***index.html should stay same.*** means stay with all the form value filled by the user?

Comment: @Lemayzeur Yes. It should say same. I just want to send lots of submit to my python function but the rendering should stay same.

Comment: This is something that will require JavaScript. Here is a simple way to do it with jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

Use the same view to perform both actions.

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <p><input type = "submit" value = "submit" /></p>
</form>
```

At forms.py:

```
class LocationForm(forms.Form):
    latitude = form.CharField()
    longitude = form.CharField()
```

Then at `views.py` you do something like this:

```
class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "index.html"

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        form = LocationForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {"form": form})

    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        form = LocationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            pass  # do something with form.cleaned_data
        return render(request, self.template_name, {"form": form})
```

It is not fully covered in the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial04/) but take a look at [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/) and [generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/).

Comment: Earlier My url file was '''urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.HomePageView.as_view()),
    url(r'^submit', views.submit)
]'''. Now I changed it to urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.HomePageView.as_view()),
    url(r'^post', views.post)
]. But now I am getting the error module 'views' has no attribute 'post'

Comment: Keep just `url(r'^$', views.HomePageView.as_view())` as you will be using the same URL for both POST and GET. Don't forget to remove the `action="submit"` from the form tag at the template.